# i have problem with using h2o.predict function in R

Tags: r, data-science, h2o

i try to use `R h2o.predict` function to get prediction as data frame which consist `p0 p1 predict` columns, although even in this code i tried and get mentioned data frame,but now i get one column which consist predict. Below i will share piece of my code and result.

i tried to do some changes on my test frames (train_df and test_df) , but it does not work. Can anybody help me to get expected result which is mentioned below?

```r
h2o.init()

h2o_data = as.h2o(train_df)
train = h2o_data


Survived = 'Survived'

aml = h2o.automl(y=Survived,
                training_frame = train,
                max_runtime_secs = 12)

str(test_df)
test = as.h2o(test_df)
predictions = as.data.frame(h2o.predict(object = aml, newdata = test))
predictions
```

i excepted something like

```r
p0          p1              predict
0.124124    0.8752341         0
0.124124    0.8752341         0
0.124124    0.8752341         0
0.124124    0.8752341         0
.
.
.
```

but get

```r
        predict
1   0.052932147
2   0.302577856
3   0.131041562
4   0.210355447
5   0.534559986
6   0.123824789
7   0.557775192
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get one column which consist predict.

If your predictions look like this, it means you have trained a regression model instead of a classification model.  My guess is that your `"Survived"` column is binary, encoded as 0/1.  Since it's numeric, H2O thinks you are trying to do regression.  If you want to do a classification, you need to convert it into a factor column as follows:

```
h2o_data = as.h2o(train_df)
train = h2o_data
Survived = 'Survived'
train[,Survived] = as.factor(train[,Survived])
```